# How to prevent view resizing/transform when UINavigationBar hides/shows

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uinavigationbar, uitabbar, resize

I have an application with a tab bar and a navigation bar.  I push a view controller that is used to show photos, one at a time.  It initially shows the bars and forward/back controls; after a delay, these hide, using `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:` and a custom transform (`CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation`) on the tab bar.  This works, but the view controllers view , which shows the photo, leaps up and down.  The same is true if I leave the tab bar out of the equation.

How can I prevent the UINavigationBar from moving my view around?  I would like the photo to stay fixed in the screen, with the nav bar dropping down over the top segment of it.

Comment: I have dealt with this by ignoring the UINavigationController and presenting the image view modally.  This works, but isn't entirely satisfactory.

Comment: Hey, I managed to solve my issue - maybe it works for you too. Check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881905/imageview-changes-frame-bounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I accomplished that by disabling 'Autoresize Subviews' in Interface Builder

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
[[navigationController navigationBar] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
[[navigationController navigationBar] setAutoresizesSubviews:NO];
```

this seemed to do the trick for me!

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue and fixed it with a class that inherited from `UINavigationController`

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
}
```

Worked great for me, didn't had to set style to `UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent`. So it did kept my colors.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find a proper way to handle this except to set the navigationBar style to translucent as in:

```
theNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
```

Other than creating another navigation bar and adding buttons to them, that's the best (and it seems to be what Apple does as well in it's Photo app)