# ImageView changes frame/bounds

Tags: iphone, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, resize, uiimageview

I have been trying to find this issue here, but no topic seems to fit...
I have a UINavigationController that pushes different kinds of UIViews containing images. When the controller pushes a new view, it the navigation bar is moved onto the screen and it appears that the image subsequently is being 'squelched' a bit - or it 'moves in from top' 
(I hope I described this sufficiently).

Anyway, my image has the frame of 320x460 (because of the top bar). I couldnt find a proper setting, where the image would remain in this size. It is always 'made smaller'. Subtracting 45 px for the new navigation bar (to 320x415) didnt help either.

What am I missing? Any clues are welcome!

P.S.:Setting the resizemask to 0 didnt help either....

Comment: Same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864978/how-to-prevent-view-resizing-transform-when-uinavigationbar-hides-shows - which has no answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by changing the following:

I initially created an App using the UIViewController template. Since I wanted to use a UINavigationController to handle my navigation, I added one and put it on top(!) of my RootViewController.

Here's what I think might have happened: Whenever I pushed a new view onto my NavigationController it seemed to slide in from above - something I didn't want to see. This may be because the UIViewController 'behind' my NavigationController had a different frame layout, namely those pixels taken by the top navigation bar.

Well, I created a new App recently, using the UINavigationController Template. I deleted the TableView and added a regular view as its view. Now pushing and popping new view controllers works just fine - the slide is gone :)

Hope I could help someone.